# How to block specific websites in my own browser using java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm building my own browser using android studio. I need to block specific websites in the browser e.g facebook.com, youtube.com. How can I do that.

```
package com.example.privatebrowser;

 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.webkit.WebSettings;
 import android.webkit.WebView;
 import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView pb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.privatebrowser);
    pb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    pb.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");

    WebSettings webSettings = pb.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

}
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if(pb.canGoBack()){
        pb.goBack();
    }
    else
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom WebView client

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {

        String url = request.getUrl().toString();
        //Log.e("url", URL);

        if(url.contains("url you want to block") {
             //do whatever you want to do
        } else {
            view.loadUrl(url);
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
 
    }
}
```

Then set above WebClient in your WebView

```
pb.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

Comment: I can't figure it out completely. Can you please arrange our both java codes in a working sequence.